# convert from XY coordinate to LatLong

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I'm new to all this systems and world !
I have some points represented in the XY coordinate in Tunisia and I'm looking for a library to transform those points. 
for example : `x = -92336.468 / y = 99043.202` and the origin of the XY coordinate is : `lat: 33.8869 ; long: 9.5375`
when I use this website [converter from XY to Lat-Long](http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFutility.html) I get the adequate result when testing the results on google map .
What's the algo of the conversion or if there is a ready Library that would be awesome.

Comment: do you have a language in mind?

Comment: Javascript would be good

Comment: http://proj4js.org/

Comment: I came past this library but didn't dive into it. I will check it and tell you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/). It look pretty easy to use. You will need the projection parameters witch you can search with this site http://epsg.io/. To work with google map you will need to transform them in WGS84. And i can't post the link of that one because it seem that i do not have the reputation points :(.

Comment: what's the epsg of X and Y coordinate system with specified origin.
I couldn't find it in epsg.io

Comment: Well I really don't know what is used in Tunisia. It should be there, but there may be others websites that can help you find the projections parameters too. That is the one you want to convert to: proj4.defs("EPSG:4326","+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs");

Comment: thank you for the help. I just thought that the source epsg is international also since I was able to get the right result with this website : http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFutility.html

Comment: There you have it it's UTM coordinates.

Comment: I'll find your parameters :P

Comment: hahah thx a lot. 
I found this one : https://epsg.io/22332 
I'm gone test it

Comment: I guess the library is broken I get :
..\proj4\lib\core.js:25
  if (item.oProj) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'oProj' of undefined

Comment: I guess it's this EPSG : http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/
but do you know how to change the location cause it's by default in (0,0)

Comment: The website you give also have this http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFref.txt you can try it out.